# How to update UI after delay in swift

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, autolayout, swift4

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.5) { animations() }
```

I make changes with UI (in main thread) and I need to delay further animations for a while and then execute them (synchronously). Code above works, but with "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes" error.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What are you doing in `animations()`? Background stuff?

Comment: @fguchelaar No, animations() is a UI-changes block.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a delay like this

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0.5, options: [], animations: {
   /// animations here
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I tried to avoid using this function. Is there any other way?